# I want to find out where the focus belongs after EN_KILLFOCUS?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, mfc

Now I have build my application like this: it runs in the container of Internet browser(IE, FireFox, Chrome and so on). There is a modeless dialog in my program, the dialog contains one CEdit control.

Here is my problem: when user activate the Edit control to type into something, the edit control get the focus. When the edit control loses the focus, I must check whether the input is valid. If not, I will display a model dialog with

AfxMessageBox

. But now I cannot determine whether my edit control loses in my own application. Because the edit control may loses focus by a lot of means, for example, when user close the browser, when user open a text program. In these cases, I will just skip the invalidation check.

Any one can tell me how to find that in which way my edit control loses focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call GetFocus() and see if the focus has gone back to another window in your thread.

```
HWND hwndFocus = ::GetFocus();
if (hwndFocus != 0 && ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwndFocus, NULL) == ::GetCurrentThreadId())
{
    // focus still in our thread
}
```